# Leave one out crossvalind in Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, training-data

I have extracted HOG features for male and female pictures, now, I'm trying to use the *Leave-one-out-method* to classify my data. 
Due the standard way to write it in Matlab is:

```
[Train, Test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut', N, M);
```

What I should write instead of `N` and `M`?
Also, should I write above code statement inside or outside a loop?
this is my code, where I have training folder for Male (80 images) and female (80 images), and another one for testing (10 random images).

```
for i = 1:10  
 [Train, Test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut', N, 1);
 SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training_Set (Train), train_label (Train));
 Gender = svmclassify(SVMStruct, Test_Set_MF (Test)); 
end
```

Notes:

- `Training_Set`: an array consist of HOG features of training folder images.
- `Test_Set_MF`: an array consist of HOG features of test folder images.
- `N`: total number of images in training folder.
- SVM should detect which images are male and which are female.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will focus on how to use `crossvalind` for the *leave-one-out*-method.

I assume you want to select random sets inside a loop. `N` is the length of your data vector. `M` is the number of randomly selected observations in `Test`. Respectively `M` is the number of observations left out in `Train`. This means you have to set `N` to the length of your training-set. With `M` you can specify how many values you want in your `Test`-output, respectively you want to left out in your `Train`-output.

Here is an example, selecting `M=2` observations out of the dataset.

```
dataset = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
N = length(dataset);
M = 2;

for i = 1:5
    [Train, Test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut', N, M);
    % do whatever you want with Train and Test
    dataset(Test) % display the test-entries
end
```

This outputs: *(this is generated randomly, so you won't have the same result)*

```
ans =
     1     9
ans =
     6     8
ans =
     7    10
ans =
     4     5
ans =
     4     7
```

---

As you have it **in your code** according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353483/how-to-add-hog-features-into-matrix-matlab), you need to adjust it for a matrix of features:

```
Training_Set = rand(10,3);     % 10 samples with 3 features each

N = size(Training_Set,1);
M = 2;

for i = 1:5
    [Train, Test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut', N, 2);
    Training_Set(Train,:) % displays the data to train
end
```

Comment: I understood that 'N' = the number of samples I have in training folder. 'M' = the number of test sample which will stay out in each loop, ex: (1). The loop should be from 1 to : number of samples I want to test. Am I write?

Comment: Could you help me? @ParagS.Chandakkar; @rayryeng

Comment: Still one more question Mr. Matt. Why you set the loop from 1:5? why not 1:10 so it will be equal to length of dataset? @Matt

Comment: @AbuQusay: The 5 just defines the number of loops and therefore is the number of test-cases being generated. You can set it to a number you define independently from the length of the dataset.

Comment: Really thanks Mr. Matt, your answers were so helpful to me. My best regards.